# Python NFL Fantasy CSV

Tags: python, csv

Excuse my ignorance here but I'm having a difficult time getting Python to do what I want it to do. So basically, I have a CSV file that contains National Football League(NFL) data that includes four rows which are Position, PlayerName, Salary, and Average fantasy points a game(AFPG). So for example of what it would look like in the CSV file would be Position(RB), PlayerName(Le'Veon Bell) Salary(9800) AvgFantasyPoints(28.6). What I would like to do is select a PlayersName who averages at least 14 AFPG and is less than 7000 Salary. Here is the code I have so far below. Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
import csv

out=open("NFL.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.reader(out, delimiter = ",")
data = csv.reader(out)
data = [row for row in data]

for row  in data:
    Position = row[0]
    Name = row[1]
    Salary = row[2]
    Game_info = row[3]
    Avg_points = row[4]
    Players = (Name)
    for field in Salary:
        print(if Salary <= 7000)

out.close()
```

Comment: Could you provide the content of the csv file?

Comment: as @stamaimer said, post your csv file and perhaps you cold look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) module to work with csv files

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import csv

data = csv.DictReader(open('filename.csv'))

players = [i['Name'] for i in data if i['Salary'] < 7000 and i['Ave_points'] >= 14]
```

If you do not have file headers in the form `Position,Name,Salary,Game_pts,Ave_pts`, you can use `collections.namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

stats = namedtuple("stats", "position, name, salary, gamepts, avepts")

data = map(stats._make, csv.reader(open("filename.txt")))

new_data = [i.name for i in data if i.salary > 7000 and i.avepts >= 14]
```